# Laravel dusk error on js submit failed to load resource: err_file_not_found

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, jquery-forms-plugin, laravel-dusk

I have an error on

```
php artisan dusk
```

error on cosole said

```
Failed to load resouces: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Manually run the test on browser the no such error found.
The routes is correct and tested. The js is working.

I use http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ for form submission.

google-chrome version 58.0.3029
php 7.0.15-1ubuntu4
ubuntu  17.04
apache2 2.4.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rewrite the code, it seem that the file $browser->attach() i'm using not have permission to read the file.
It seem okay when the file name is displayed in the form while the file itself doesn't have the right permission or even file not exist.